# Period of Paper Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

A threatening note written on 8.5x11 inch paper is pinned to the door of a physics professor. The perpetrator left in a hurry so that when the physics professor finds the paper it is still swinging. Assuming the pin is at the very top center of the paper, what is the period of the paper’s motion?

Comment: This question uses a single basic formula. Try solving it!

Comment: Did the pysics professor come from from inside his office?

Comment: I'm not sure, all I know is that the moment of inertia used is I = (1/12) M(a^2 + b^2). That's the only hint my professor gave me.

Comment: Look up `physical pendulum` in your text. Check to see if the moment of inertia he gave you is for center of mass or the actual pin point. Or you could write the torque equation and solve the DE for small angle oscillations.